# WordPress site user-login: 404 page not found

Tags: wordpress

How can I debug and understand what is wrong with our WordPress site?

The site is working, but I can’t log into the WordPress console, `http://example.com/user-login`. I get “404 page not found”.

I am using Apache, but I do not think it is related to the problem.
I transferred the site from [WP Engine](https://wpengine.com/) to an [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) instance: is there something that maybe I forgot to do? (I already did the database migrate.)

Comment: Check for the logs `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and `/var/log/httpd/access_log`  The log files are configuration dependent  so check your `httpd.conf` or your vhost file if you have any

Comment: thanks, I know apache and nothing there, the question is if there anyway to check if something worng on wordpress side.

Comment: Check if there are permissions problems. Modify your `php.ini` to enable debugging.

Comment: thanks, everything ok with the permissions, do you know how to enable debugging with `php.ini` ? do you know how I can find my wordpress login page ?

Comment: ok i found the issue, the login was from `example.com/wp-admin` and not `user-login`, is it possible to switch from `wp-admin` to `user-login`, should be done with wordpress? I know how to do it with apache, but maybe there is another way

Comment: @Berlin you can use plugins for that.

Comment: Please [edit] clarifications into the post itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wp-admin is used for back-end access into Wordpress you really do not want to change that as it is  hard-coded into the WordPress sytem, so every admin link will point back to the original folder, and you’ll never see any admin pages at all.

user-login is usually used for frontend login for users, creating post, comments etc. this is usually accomplished through a plug in.

If you are looking to harden you wordpress install follow this:

https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/

Comment: thank you, do you suggest to change the frontend-login page maybe with some plugin ?